# Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\distro\application\views\baju.php on line 13

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass value from my model to view, but error

error message below

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function result() on a non-object
>
> Filename: views/baju.php
>
> Line Number: 13
>
> Backtrace:

this my model

```
<?php
class Baju extends CI_Model{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function tampil_semua_baju(){
        $query = $this->db->get('baju');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

this my controller

```
<?php
class Baju_C extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function tampil_data(){
        $this->load->model('Baju','all_item');
        $data['item_baju'] = $this->all_item->tampil_semua_baju();
        $this->load->view('baju',$data);
    }
}
```

this my view

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Little Monster</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="wodth=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url('asset/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url('asset/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('asset/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js') ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('asset/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            foreach($item_baju->result() as $hasil):
        ?>
        <p><?php echo $hasil->nama; ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you `autoload` the database library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your view like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Little Monster</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="wodth=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url('asset/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url('asset/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('asset/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js') ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('asset/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            foreach($item_baju as $hasil):
        ?>
        <p><?php echo $hasil->nama; ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you - i did not know about renaming models like that.